# Format the request body for a multipart/related upload to google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-storage

Following [Google's JSON API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload) for multipart uploads I have constructed this request body. I'm using the result of FileReader's readAsDataURL as the binary file in my request body.

I keep getting the error "malformed multipart body" but don't know which part of the request body is wrong...

Any support would be appreciated.

```js
let requestBody =
'--foo_bar_baz\r\n' +
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
JSON.stringify({'name': 'myObject'}) + '\r\n' +
'--foo_bar_baz\r\n' +
'Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n' +
binaryFileData + '\r\n' +
'--foo_bar_baz--';

let url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/${bucketID}/o?uploadType=multipart`

let headers = {
'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz',
};


this.$http({
  url: url, 
  method: 'POST', 
  data: requestBody,
  headers: headers
})
```

Comment: Can you add an image of your network tab in developer tools when the request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you  might be missing the blank line between your headers and your data.

Comment: I attached the '\r\n' directly to the end of both headers, is that incorrect?

Comment: There needs to be an empty line between the last header in each section and the start of data, so two total line breaks.